# Python: Print List Items Not in Separate Index List

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:
`list = ["a","b","c","d"]`
`i_to_skip = [0,2]`

I'd like to print everything in `list` except for the indices in `i_to_skip`. I've tried the following, which just returns a generator object:

`print(x for x in list if x not in i_to_skip)`

Comment: How do you want the output formatted.  One item per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your comprehension does work is that `x` is the *value*, like `"a"`, not the *index*, like `0`, and of course `"a"` is not in `[0, 2]`.

To get the index along with the value, you need [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Then you can do this:

```
print([x for i, x in enumerate(list) if i not in i_to_skip])
```

Also, note that printing a generator expression (as you did) is just going to print something like `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1055fd8b8>`; that's why I converted your code to printing out a list comprehension, so you get `['b', 'd']` instead.

---

If you instead wanted to print, say, one line at a time, you could loop over the generator expression:

```
for x in (x for i, x in enumerate(list) if i not in i_to_skip):
    print(x)
```

But really, it's easier to just collapse that into a single loop:

```
for i, x in emumerate(list):
    if i not in i_to_skip:
        print(x)
```

Or, even simpler, format the whole thing in a single expression, maybe like this:

```
print('\n'.join(x for i, x in enumerate(list) if i not in i_to_skip))
```

… or even let `print` do it for you:

```
print(*(x for i, x in enumerate(list) if i not in i_to_skip), sep='\n')
```

---

Finally, as a side note, calling your list `list` is a bad idea; it hides the type/constructor function, which may want to use later on, and it also makes your code misleading.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for all of the additional information. And no worries, my list isn't actually called `list`, that was just for this example

Comment: As I was reading this, I kept thinking "This answer really should also mention ____", only to scroll down a little and see it mentioned. Bravo.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I was probably editing just fast enough to keep up with your reading. :)

Comment: @Adam_G: It's arguably even worse to use in examples. In your real code, at least you can know whether or not your real code needs to use the actual `list` constructor; in an example, people have to worry about whether it's possibly affecting your problem in some way…

Comment: joining a list would be more efficient.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: More efficient than _what_? And besides, who cares? You really think any of these options is going to be a performance bottleneck in the OP's code?

Comment: @abarnert, 1. I care. 2. it is more efficient than a generator expression  3. It is also well documented that using join on a list is more efficient and I am sure there are other people out there who do care.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: In this case, the `join` call takes 1.16us with a genexpr, 1.09us with a list. Over 90% of the time is spent in the `not in` clause (which will only get worse if `i_to_skip` is larger). And meanwhile, the `print` part takes 13.9us, so the whole `join` expression is only 10% of the total time for just this line. It's hard to find a better case of optimizing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your print result is a **generator** , you need to put your list comprehension in a list sign (`[]`) or use `list()` function,
also you need to check the indices not the values , so you can figure it out with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) :

```
>>> print ([j for i,j in enumerate(list) if i not in i_to_skip] )
['b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = ["a","b","c","d"]
print([x for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if i not in i_to_skip])
```

You shouldn't call your list `list` or you're hiding the `list` type itself.

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) will give you the indexes and corresponding elements of the list.

Putting the comprehension in square brackets makes it into a list, which is easier to print than a generator.